# How to disable Toggle Maximization State in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, dconf, gsettings

How to disable **Toggle Maximization State** in VM Ubuntu 16.04.

I have tried to disable **Toggle Maximization State** by setting values in dconf database.

```
dconf load / << EOF 
[org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings]
toggle-maximized=['disabled']
EOF
```

And also tried on my VirtualBox 16.04 LTS has two Compiz profiles - unity and unity-lowgfx.

```
dconf load / << EOF 
[org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core]
toggle-maximized=['disabled']
EOF

dconf load / << EOF 
[org/compiz/profiles/unity-lowgfx/plugins/core]
toggle-maximized=['disabled']
EOF
```

But issue not resolved yet. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Disableg shortcuts from cli

To disable shortcuts in `gsettings`, usually the value should be set to `[]`.

In this case, in a command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings toggle-maximized '[]'
```

#### GUI

As always, there is also a gui-alternative: `dconf-editor`, installed by:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Subsequently, browse to the key, uncheck "Use default value" and set it to `[]`

[image]

Comment: Followed your advice, but if I press  (Alt + F10) key. It's opening status menu(indicator) on the top bar. I don't want to be open status menu , it should also disable . How to disable it?

Comment: @Dinesh Toggle maximized is disabled by this procedure though, but I can understand you don't want it to do anything at all. On a 16.04 VM / Unity, it indeed opens the menu. I am afraid it is a built-in shortcut in Unity, which cannot be disabled. The fact that it is in the oversight if you press <Super> indeed supports the impression.